# Magento 2 security scan showing file is publicly accessible over HTTP

Tags: magento2

After a security issue in Magento marketplace account which was held on November 21, 2019.

So Adobe instruct to store owner to do website scanning via https://account.magento.com/scanner

After successful scanning, I got the following message.

> We have determined that your Magento installation's configuration
>   file(s) are publicly accessible over HTTP.
>
> **File: .user.ini**

And as I checked `.user.ini` file its permission is `644`.

Looking for help to solve a publically accessible file.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your nginx config.

```
location ~ \.user\.ini$ {
    deny all;
}
```